# Вращение объекта относительно другого объекта

Tags: c#, unity3d

В книжке "Джозеф Хокинг - Unity в действии" наткнулся на скрипт. Вроде бы все понятно, но одна строка вызывает у меня вопросы...

```
transform.position = target.position - (rotation * _offset);
```

1. Каким образом можно прийти к этой формуле самому?
2. **Почему/Зачем/Для чего**   rotation умножаем на _offset, и от target.position вычитаем результат умножения?
3. Какие источники по данной теме вы посоветуете?

Прошу, объясните как работает эта формула и как к ней прийти самому без подсказок.

Ниже я оставил скрин и листинг кода.

[image: скрипт]

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class OrbitCamera : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    private Transform target;
    public float rotSpeed = 1.5f;
    private float _rotY;
    private Vector3 _offset;

    void Start()
    {
        _rotY = transform.eulerAngles.y;
        _offset = target.position - transform.position;
    }
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        float horInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        if (horInput != 0)
        {
            _rotY += horInput * rotSpeed;
        }
        else
        {
            _rotY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotSpeed * 3;
        }
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, _rotY, 0);
        transform.position = target.position - (rotation * _offset);//непонятно
        transform.LookAt(target);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Позиционирование точки в пространстве

Начать стоит с самой базовой концепции в положении объекта в пространстве - векторов. Не секрет, что Transform.position - это 3х мерный вектор, который хранит положение точки в 3д пространстве относительно какой-то точки. Самый распространенный случай - начало координат, классическая точка (0, 0, 0):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Важно понимать, что такой вектор - **относительная** величина, он может указывать позицию точки как относительно "глобального начала координат", так и какой-нибудь другой точки, это важно для вашего примера.

Поскольку Transform.position задается, зачастую, относительно глобальных координат, нужно как-то найти этот вектор. Находится он просто - складываем 2 вектора, как учили в школе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На этом легкие азы векторов заканчиваются.

---

### Вращение точки в пространстве

Давным-давно использовались так называемые **углы Эйлера** - довольно простой способ повернуть объект относительно одной или нескольких осей. Все просто: есть 3 оси - (x, y, z), задаем угол вращения относительно каждой оси и вуаля - получаем вращение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все было бы хорошо, но у углов Эйлера есть одна большая проблема - Gimbal lock (переводов много, самый распространенный - *шарнирный замок*). Я не буду вдаваться в подробности - не об этом вопрос, и просто прикреплю ссылку на русскоязычную статью. Сейчас важно понимать, что Unity использует кватернионы для вращения объектов в пространстве, а не углы Эйлера.

Основной посыл здесь - пояснить, почему используется `Quaternion` и `Quaternion.Euler`.

---

### Объяснение приведенной формулы вращения

`target.position - (rotation * _offset)`

Для более внятного объяснения уберем объект, будем вращаться относительно начала координат.

Если ничего не делать, объект будет просто в начале мировых координат - (0, 0, 0). Вместо всякий вращений просто добавим смещение, например (1, 0, 0): `transform.position = _offset;`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
*Куб* - начало мировых координат, *сфера* - объект, к которому применяется формула.

---

**Тут стоит понять, что вообще означает умножение Quaternion на Vector3.** Вычисление расположения точки в пространстве - это комбинация Масштабирования - Scale, Вращения - Rotation и Смещения - Translation. Поскольку масштабирование нас не особо интересует, мы остановимся на последних двух. Углубляться в теорию не особо хочется - это уже отдельный вопрос, так что за ответом мы сходим в [документацию `Quaternion.operator *`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-operator_multiply.html):

> *public static Vector3 operator *(Quaternion rotation, Vector3 point);*
>   Description 
>   **Rotates** the point *point* with *rotation*.

Подобного оператора у Vector3 нет, из чего уже можно сделать вывод, что для вращения точки нужно умножать кватернион на вектор, а не наоборот. Если знакомы с понятием матрицы, то ответ еще проще, мы умножаем вращение на вектор, а не наоборот, т.к. **умножение матриц - операция не коммутативная**, умножать нужно именно в таком порядке, почему - гуглим, Trasform - тема отдельного большого вопроса :)

---

Вернемся к нашему объекту в Unity и пропишем в Update строку: `(rotation * _offset)`, как я описал выше. Применим какое-нибудь вращение, скажем, 30 градусов относительно оси y, получим примерно такую картину, если смотреть сверху:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И что-то подобное в Unity:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот на таком простом умножении (не путать, начинка и теория у этого кода сложная) и строится базовое вращение в пространстве.

---

### Последние штрихи

Вернемся к идее "вращение вокруг данного объекта".

Данная задача решается точно так же, как и вращение выше. Единственное отличие - выше мы вращали точку вокруг начала мировых координат, а сейчас мы хотим вращать точку относительно какого-то другого объекта.

Чтобы от мировых координат перейти к координатам относительно какого-то объекта, нужно всего лишь сложить 2 вектора, о чем я писал в самом начале, складываем вектор цели со заданным смещением и получаем вектор относительно мировых координат: `transform.position = target.position - _offset;`

Поскольку вектор _offset, по сути, является координатой точки **относительно** цели, мы должны вращать этот вектор, а это мы уже умеем:

`transform.position = target.position - (rotation * _offset);`

Вот мы и получили данную в книге формулу, осталась лишь одна деталь - знак минуса. На самом деле это не важно, отрицание вектора лишь инвертирует его, а значит `-(rotation * _offset)` и `(rotation * _offset)` - противоположные вектора, но при этом направление поворота у них одинаковое. Так что можете использовать или то или другое, зависит от того, как вы хотите изначально расположить объект и как вам удобнее располагать его на сцене

---

### Полезные ссылки

[Перевод туториала по OpenGL на тему Transform`а](https://habr.com/post/319144/)

[Что такое Gimbal Lock](https://habr.com/post/183116/)

[Статья про то, как в целом функционирует компонент Transform в Unity путем написания онного с нуля](https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/rendering/part-1/)